# how to convert Layout view to Bitmap excluding some components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap

in my layout I have a background, button and a textView, the button here serves to convert my view to bitmap and save it

I managed to do that but my png Image contains the save button as well,

I'm using this line  to get the drawing from my layout :

```
Bitmap cache = vw.getDrawingCache();
```

What I want to achieve is that before getting the screen from the view , I want it to not consider my button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a free design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Using canvas to draw layout like this

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    layout.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: thank you Anand but  I want to paint just layout with its background and textView without the button

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at setting the component to visibility gone?

```
Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
saveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then after you get your snapshot make sure you do

```
saveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The problem with this solution is that the screenshot will still contain the gap where the button was. The view does not get redrawn before the bitmap is saved. I have tried calling `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` with no success (which is why I found your question).

Also, another alternative is to do something like what Anand said by drawing it to a Canvas. This is useful if your view is larger than the screen. By drawing it to a Canvas you can get the entire view. By going this route, you can have a container with your background and TextView and have the button outside that container. You can then get just the view with the container. (I can't use this solution since my button is in the middle of my desired data)

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.my_view); // the view containing your text view
// not needed since it is outside your my_view now
// v.findViewById(R.id.save_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
// not needed since it is outside your my_view now
// v.findViewById(R.id.save_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// your Bitmap "b" now contains the image you want
```